# Powering a very simple accordion with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="questions-answers">
    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">Question 1</a></h3>
        <div>Odio natoque est sagittis, elementum turpis porttitor velit amet? Aenean? Sociis tincidunt magnis natoque ultrices, nunc ultrices, elementum? Augue velit integer, elementum adipiscing. Integer mauris ultrices massa odio.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">Question 2</a></h3>
        <div>Tincidunt, tincidunt magna. Ultricies platea. Vel augue tempor sit scelerisque pulvinar! Nisi, auctor sed, lundium adipiscing aliquet, et magna? Arcu nec vut ultricies elementum odio sociis mauris sit?</div>
    <li>
    <!-- at least 7 more -->
</ul>
```

What I need to achieve using jQuery is, when one a is clicked, the div in that same li is revealed and all other div are hidden. When a different a is clicked, the div in that li is shown and again all other div are hidden.

Hope that makes sense!

EDIT to add jQuery code.

Sorry, I should've added my jQuery:

```
$('.questions-answers li div').hide();
$( ".questions-answers h3 a" ).click(function() {
   $('.questions-answers li div').hide();
   $(this).next("div").show();
});
```

Comment: just google a bit please : jquery accordion

Comment: Sorry, I've just added my jQuery so far. Its line 4 that doesn;t seem to work. The other 3 are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is since you have binded the click handler to the anchor element, the next element is not the div, it is the parent h3 element's next sibling

```
var $divs = $('.questions-answers li > div').hide();
$(".questions-answers li > h3 a").click(function () {

    var $div = $(this).parent().next("div").show();
    $divs.not($div).hide();
});
```

or bind the handler to h3

```
var $divs = $('.questions-answers li > div').hide();
$(".questions-answers li > h3").click(function () {
    var $div = $(this).next("div").show();
    $divs.not($div).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the 2nd method works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
 $('ul').find('div').hide();
 $(this).parent('li').find('div').show();
});
```

I haven't tested, but will work hopefully.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I can't get it to work - I've added the jQuery I have so far to my original question.